# request data in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    type = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.HiddenInput( attrs = {'value': 'how_to_get_value_from_request'} )
    )
```

I want when user opens www.site.com/order/type/t1 `hidden value = "t1"` 
 
www.site.com/order/type/t2 `hidden value = "t2"` 
www.site.com/order/type/t3 `hidden value = "t3"`

etc.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you pass values to a form. You do it when you instantiate the form, in your view:

```
def my_view(request):
    form = SomeForm(initial={'type': 'the_value_I_want'})
```